# Can databases encrypted with Laravel or any other encryption method be decrypted?

Tags: laravel, security, encryption, database-design, password-encryption

everyone. I'm learning Laravel and I'm in the start of my journey. I was learning about encryption and decryption in Laravel today and then this thought came into my mind. Could be a stupid one but I want to know my answers.

Let's say I make a database which stores sensitive information about users and I encrypt all the data before storing into the database, let's just say using the Encrypt class of Laravel. Now my questions:

- If someone steals that database and luckily finds out that this information was encrypted using techniques provided by Laravel or any other technique. Can't that person descript that all data using the same decryption technique that was used to encrypt it. If this can be done, then what's the point of doing this encryption?
- If that can be done then how can we make sure that our data is actually encrypted and is safe even if someone steals it?

Thank you guys!

I encrypted my data and then decrypted it and want my answer that how that encrypted data is even safe.

Comment: Basically depends on type of algorithm for a starter if its hashed then its not possible for decreypt the data else if you want you can look for AES encryption or The method that you want (encrypt class) uses a key for encrypting so you can decrypt later references: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/encryption

Comment: Encrypted data is not meant to be 100% secure, it is meant to obfuscate (hide, make harder to read, etc), and it can be decrypted. Hashed data on the other hand _is_ meant to be secure. When you hash something, you cannot un-hash it, you can only compare other hashed values to see if they match (they will not be exactly the same, like `Hash::make('one') == Hash::make('one')` is `false`). Depending on the type of sensitive information, and if you need to see it's plain-text value, you'd use hashing or encrypting.

Comment: If you encrypt data with the Encrypt facade provided by Laravel, the APP_KEY env variable is used as the encryption key.
This means if anyone gets access to your encrypted data, they would need to have access to this encryption key to decrypt it, otherwise they would have to brut force to get the key which is practically impossible considering the standard of encryption Laravel uses. So what you need to worry about is how save this key is.

Comment: Generally nothing is imperivious to being comprimised. If someone steals your database data and it's encrypted, they can't realistically do anything with that data unless they also steal your encryption key. If it's sufficiently hard to steal your database data to begin with, and also sufficiently hard to steal your encryption key, then it will probably not be worth the time and effort of anyone to steal your data. That of course depends on how valuable that data is, so the more valuable the data the more persistent attacks you can expect.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read up on the [basics of encryption](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/beginners-guide-to-the-basics-of-data-encryption/).

The common approach is that the *technique* by which you encrypt should be as open as possible - because the more people look at the algorithm, the less likely there might be bugs.

However, even if the algorithm is public, the *key* is not. Only people who have the key can decrypt properly encrypted data. This is true of the AES algorithm Laravel uses too.

The mathematics are complicated, but essentially the length of the key determines the amount of computer resources required to break the encryption.

THe real-world example is that everyone knows how door locks work. There are millions of locks that all work in the same way - but only people who have a key can open the door.

So, if an attacker steals your database, they cannot read your content unless they *also* have the key, as long as the key length is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

**If someone steals that database and luckily finds out that this information was encrypted using techniques provided by Laravel or any other technique. Can't that person descript that all data using the same decryption technique that was used to encrypt it. If this can be done, then what's the point of doing this encryption?**

If someone steals that database they will still need a decryption key to decrypt (thats why strong passwords are recommended) so even if they bruteforce it will become almost impossible to decrypt.

The way you’re asking if encrypt and decrypt is easy then i think you’re asking some encryption like base64.

With AES bruteforcing their way in becomes difficult. In laravel encrypt or crypt class it uses **AES-256-CBC** which is pretty good at that.

Then there is Hash library they are one way encryption techniques which uses bcrypt it can only be verified and not decrypt you have to run all combinations for lines everytime to brute force. Unlike md5 which gives same encryted string every time.